# ¿como puedo actualizar mi listview al agregar un archivo nuevo?

Tags: java, android, listview

¿como puedo actualizar mi listview  al agregar un archivo nuevo? el listView es alimentado por los nombres de archivos .xml que son guardados en un path en especifico ya lei bastante e intente varias cosas pero nada resulta. Lo que encuentro principalmente es esta función pero no me sirve

Nota: lo archivos los estoy agregando desde una parte de la app que esta en c++ es una app híbrida este es el path

> File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/cc.openframeworks.androidMultiOFActivitiesExample/files/xml");

Aqui esta el codigo del listView:

De aqui obtengo los archivos para el listView:

> activity.java  en
>
> on create:

```
 ListView list2;

CustomList listAdapter;
 String[] ficheros;

 final File carpeta = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/cc.openframeworks.androidMultiOFActivitiesExample/files/xml");
        listarFicherosPorCarpeta(carpeta);
        ficheros = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

         listAdapter =  new CustomList(OFActivityA.this, ficheros,fecha);
           list2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
            list2.setAdapter(listAdapter);

          public void listarFicherosPorCarpeta(final File carpeta) {


                for (final File ficheroEntrada: carpeta.listFiles()) {

                    if (ficheroEntrada.isDirectory()) {
                        listarFicherosPorCarpeta(ficheroEntrada);

                    } else {
                        System.out.println(ficheroEntrada.getName());

                        list.add(ficheroEntrada.getName());
                    }
                }

            }

    @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();

                if (list2!= null) {
                    list2.invalidateViews();
                }
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

> CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] ficheros;
    private final String[] fecha;

    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] ficheros, String[] fecha) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, ficheros);
        this.context = context;
        this.ficheros = ficheros;
        this.fecha = fecha;
//        this.imageId = imageId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listtext);
        TextView txtFecha = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.fechatxt);
        txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#015D99"));
        txtTitle.setHeight(125);
        txtFecha.setText(fecha[position]);
        txtTitle.setText(ficheros[position]);


        return rowView;
    }
```

¿me falta algo del codigo o el orden?¿ de que forma puedo actualizar la lista?

Comment: Puedes poner el código completo ya que lo que has añadido no cuadra. Estas añadiendo los objetos del listView a la variable list cuando al listView lo estas inicializando con la variable fichero.

Comment: Esa linea no va perdon , acomode mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Prueba añadiendo el código dentro del onResume().

Answer (score 0):

El error es que tu no estas en otra `Activity` por lo que no se ejecuta el On Resume, trata lo siguiente:

Haces una llamada a `refreshDisplay` y alli tienes lo que desees.

```
private void refreshDisplay() {
        actualizas tu lista
        ...
        list2.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```